# how can I find a function that satisfies cauchy functional equation?

Tags: real-analysis

Can any one help please? I tried to find some linear functions that satisfying $$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$ but the condition of scalar that says: $$f(ax)=a\cdot f(x)$$ does not hold in cauchy functional equation $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$

Comment: Try a linear function and see if it works.  For instance, take an easy one like $f(x) = 4x$.

Comment: Well, if the function is $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, **it looks like** you just need a $\mathbb Q$-linear map that is not $\mathbb R$-linear.

Comment: thank you sir for your help.

Comment: There are two kinds of "linear", the linear maps, which have the properties you check and linear functions $y = m x + n$ which are affine maps in the context of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for. Start with a *Hamel basis* $H$ (of $\Bbb R$ over the rational field $\Bbb Q$). This is a set $H\subset\Bbb R$ such that every $x\in \Bbb R$ has a unique representation
$x=\sum_{k=1}^n q_kh_k$, where $n\in\Bbb N$, $q_k\in\Bbb Q$ and $h_k\in H$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. Define $f$ *arbitrarily* on $H$, and then extend $f$ to all of $\Bbb R$ by the recipe
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n q_kf(h_k)
$$
in case 
$$
x=\sum_{k=1}^n q_kh_k.
$$
The function $f$ so defined satisfies the Cauchy functional equation, but need not be linear.

Comment: thank you so much sir. your answer is very helpful.